# Problem when changing text on input text when user write somethings

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QZcjg/) code :

```
<input type="text" id="myText" class="input_box_hidden" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    var nomeAzienda=$("#myText");

    if(nomeAzienda.val()=="") nomeAzienda.val("Nome Azienda");
    if(nomeAzienda.val()!="Nome Azienda") nomeAzienda.removeClass().addClass("input_box");

    $("#myText").focus(function() {
        if(nomeAzienda.hasClass("input_box_hidden")) 
        {
            nomeAzienda.val("");
            nomeAzienda.removeClass().addClass("input_box");
        }
    });

    $("#myText").blur(function() {
        if(nomeAzienda.val()=="") 
        {
            nomeAzienda.val("Nome Azienda");
            nomeAzienda.removeClass().addClass("input_box_hidden");
        }
    });               
});
```

It works perfectly.

The problem is that : when I submit the input box to the server, I store the value when the client reply (so the user should not insert the value another time).

With this control :

```
    if(nomeAzienda.val()!="Nome Azienda") nomeAzienda.removeClass().addClass("input_box");
```

I check it's not the default value.

But what's if the user insert "Nome Azienda" as value? It doesnt works.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: HTML5 provides a placeholder attribute for text inputs.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not working on HTML5 (not supported in many browsers unfortunatly)

Comment: You want the same behavior if the user enters "Nome Azienda" in the input text field? So if someone types "Nome Azienda", blurs out then focuses in to have it disappear?

Comment: HTML5 placeholder has pretty strong support. Just IE is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..then you're stuffed. but seriously, i think it's perfectly fine, you never know, there might be a company called "*Company name*". At least I've seen this problem everywhere *textbox watermarks* were used, so your solution is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand, but if you want the filed to get the `input_box_hidden` class when the user inputs 'Nome Azienda', then you can add this to the blur function, right after the first `if` statement:

```
else if(nomeAzienda.val().toLowerCase()=='nome azienda')
{
   nomeAzienda.val("Nome Azienda");//correct char case for user input
   nomeAzienda.removeClass().addClass("input_box_hidden");
}
```